# How to use Year picker for asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I had one field something like HolidayYear such that is given below,

```
 [Required]
 [DisplayName(Constants.DisplayName.HolidayYear)]
 public virtual int HolidayYear { get; set; }
```

In which event I have to pick year only for the HolidayYear textbox, don't want to use date picker. So what are the code I need to add to this. Can anyone please, help to find the solution...
And my cshtml file is following

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
               <label for="" class="control-label">
                    Year
               </label>
                <br />
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HolidayYear, new { @class = "form-control"  
                                                 }).DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == true)
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If all you need is the year, why don't you have an `int` field and use for example a select with some available years?

Comment: Actually i did post wrongly, so want to change that.If you know the solution then please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a dropdown list. So instead of using `@Html.EditorFor` use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HolidayYear, HolidayController.GetDropDownListForYears())
```

Where `HolidayController.GetDropDownListForYears()` is a static method on your controller that returns a dropdownlist. It could look like this:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetDropDownListForYears()
{
    List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();

    for(int i=2014; i<=2099;i++)
    {
        ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
    }

    return ls;
}
```

Comment: you'll need `i<=2014` for your middle statement of your for loop otherwise it will only go up to 2013. i would also suggest starting from 2014 and going forward, as in context I don't think i want to go on holiday in 1900 to be honest :P

Comment: You are right about that. I will change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [kendo](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui) control for it.

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:110px" }))
```